# Break long line every N comma

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have this line with numbers separated with commas.

> 266,288,716,755,766,827,836,845,946,968,1169,1190,1266,1276,1305,1314,1323,1448,1528,1553,1558,1603,1628,1640,1666,1667,1673,1683,1689,1692,1693,1731,1746,1757,2912,3792,3813,3835,3842,3864,3883,3906,3923,3932,3958,3986,4063,4097,4271,4291,4292,4339,4360,4401,4403,4427,4551,4573,4664,4698,4762,4868,5173,5392,5551,5704,5787,5820,5873,5937,5998,6001,6009,6010,6011,6012,6013,6014,6015,6016,6017,6018,6019,6020,6022,6024,6025,6026,6027,6028,6029,6030,6032,6033,6034,6035,6036,6037,6038,6039,6040,6044,6045,6046,6047,6048,6049,6050,6051,6052,6053,6054,6055,6056,6057,6058,6060,6061,6062,6063,6064,6065,6066,6067,6068,6069,6070,6071,6072,6073,6074,6188,6261,6585,6745,6865,7077,7275,7303,7376,7422,7427,7496,7505,7532,7819,7821,7831,7939,8180,8621,9022,9092,9106,9293,9367,9441,9476,9494,9652,9717,9909,9975,9995,10096,11445,11631,12062,12936,13063,14262,14589,17420

I would find a way to break it into several lines in order to have 5 comma per line.

> 266,288,716,755,766,
> 827,836,845,946,968,
> 1169,1190,1266,1276,1305,
> 1314,1323,1448,1528,1553,
> 1558,1603,1628,1640,1666,
> 1667,1673,1683,1689,1692,
> 1693,1731,1746,1757,2912,
> 3792,3813,3835,3842,3864,
> ...

Is there an existing shortcut or extension with this feature ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RegEx search replace

Find

```
(([^,]*,){5})
```

Replace

```
$1\n
```

**Edit**

A tip from Mark:

If there are possible spaces after the `,` use

```
(([^,]*,\s*){5})
```

Comment: Did you mean replace with `$1\n`?  And match that space too: `(([^,]*,\s*){5})` so they line up better.

Comment: @Mark Thanks, I typed it a bit to fast without a test